# Vb.net - adding (or + Command) functionality dynamically

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to add OR command dynamically from access data. For e.g. if the field is no_of_keywords = 5 then my code must be:

```
 Case Test.Contains("1") Or Test.Contains("2") Or Test.Contains("3") Or Test.Contains("4") Or Test.Contains("5")
```

but i am unable to do so by any means.
i need to add this

```
Or Test.Contains("2")
```

for each keyword in database
can someone help me...
Sorry for the language... i am new to this programming language.

Comment: what is the `Select` part of the code?  And what is the question/problem - that would work as an `If` test

Comment: If it's going to be dynamic, you would have to iterate through a list.  A list of keywords and a list your are testing against and keep track with a counter.  Appending "or"s to your case statements won't work in that scenario.

Comment: @LarsTech Thank you for your answer sir, can u add a small example and your answer below so that i can accept it as the correct one?

Comment: write a small method and pass whatever you want tested for as a variable or array of items to test for